# Count specific word occurrence on page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a webpage that has a table of usernames and scores, and it changes weekly based on scores. I just want to have a number of user's shown on my page. My table has multiple 's so using a script to count those will not work.

Every row does have something in common though, the word "Score". So I figured I could just count that word, and return the value. I cannot figure out how to just count that one word after the page is loaded completely.

Help?

Edit: fixed tag

Comment: Do you want to use PHP or Java? These two are rarely mixed.

Comment: It's a php page, but I don't mind putting a little JavaScript on it. Either way.

Comment: @enjoimark Java and JavaScript are two ENTIRELY different things.

Comment: Yea I used the wrong tag. Kill me now.

Comment: This should help you on your way - [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php). Load the page content into a variable and then pass it through that as the haystack, set *score* as the needle and voilà.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post sample html code of your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple Javascript - which is done on the clients machine, so it'll save server resources.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhnLozk0/)

```
var str = document.body.innerText;
var n = str.match(/Score/ig);
```

- The `i` flag means case insensitive search
- The `g` flag means to do a global match (match all occurrences, not just one)

Answer (score 0):

Well that was easy, sorry for the bother.

I have `$playerPicks` listed in the table, so all I did was use:

```
echo count($playerPicks);
```